# How can i create Api from firebase in Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone

I have run more app.But now i want to create Api from Firebase in objective c.But after searching i can not get any sufficient link.Anybody can help me.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/

Comment: firebase framework have this all detail lease go through firebase api link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0